# PHP Group Matches (Brain Puzzler)

Tags: php

I have a brain puzzler.

I have a list of football teams and what group they are in. However when trying to generate the games for each group my head starts to hurt.

Example:

Group A

1. Russia
2. Saudi Arabia
3. Egypt
4. Uruguay

I need to make a loop which makes sure all teams have had a match with each other. So there would be 6 games per group.

Anyone know how I could tackle this?

```
$worldCupTeams = array(
    '1' => array('name' => 'Russia', 'group' => 'A'),
    '2' => array('name' => 'Saudi Arabia', 'group' => 'A'),
    '3' => array('name' => 'Egypt', 'group' => 'A'),
    '4' => array('name' => 'Uruguay', 'group' => 'A'),
    '5' => array('name' => 'Portugal', 'group' => 'B'),
    '6' => array('name' => 'Spain', 'group' => 'B'),
    '7' => array('name' => 'Morocco', 'group' => 'B'),
    '8' => array('name' => 'Iran', 'group' => 'B'),
    '9' => array('name' => 'France', 'group' => 'C'),
    '10' => array('name' => 'Australia', 'group' => 'C'),
    '11' => array('name' => 'Peru', 'group' => 'C'),
    '12' => array('name' => 'Denmark', 'group' => 'C'),
    '13' => array('name' => 'Argentina', 'group' => 'D'),
    '14' => array('name' => 'Iceland', 'group' => 'D'),
    '15' => array('name' => 'Croatia', 'group' => 'D'),
    '16' => array('name' => 'Nigeria', 'group' => 'D'),
    '17' => array('name' => 'Brazil', 'group' => 'E'),
    '18' => array('name' => 'Switzerland', 'group' => 'E'),
    '19' => array('name' => 'Costa Rica', 'group' => 'E'),
    '20' => array('name' => 'Serbia', 'group' => 'E'),
    '21' => array('name' => 'Germany', 'group' => 'F'),
    '22' => array('name' => 'Mexico', 'group' => 'F'),
    '23' => array('name' => 'Sweden', 'group' => 'F'),
    '24' => array('name' => 'South Korea', 'group' => 'F'),
    '25' => array('name' => 'Belgium', 'group' => 'G'),
    '26' => array('name' => 'Panama', 'group' => 'G'),
    '27' => array('name' => 'Tunisia', 'group' => 'G'),
    '28' => array('name' => 'England', 'group' => 'G'),
    '29' => array('name' => 'Poland', 'group' => 'H'),
    '30' => array('name' => 'Senegal', 'group' => 'H'),
    '31' => array('name' => 'Colombia', 'group' => 'H'),
    '32' => array('name' => 'Japan', 'group' => 'H')
);

$worldCupGroups = array(
    'A' => array(1, 2, 3, 4),
    'B' => array(5, 6, 7, 8),
    'C' => array(9, 10, 11, 12),
    'D' => array(13, 14, 15, 16),
    'E' => array(17, 18, 19, 20),
    'F' => array(21, 22, 23, 24),
    'G' => array(25, 26, 27, 28),
    'H' => array(29, 30, 31, 32)
);
```

All the best

David

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$matches = [];
foreach ($worldCupGroups as $groupName => $group) {
    $groupMatches = [];
    $teamHelper = [];
    foreach ($group as $team) {
        foreach ($teamHelper as $foreignTeam) {
                $groupMatches[] = [$team, $foreignTeam];
        }
        $teamHelper[] = $team;
    }
    $matches[$groupName] = $groupMatches;
}
```

The algorithm simply adds a tupel for each team, that has before been saved in a helper array. The current team just gets added to this array afterwards. Like this a team can neither play against inself, nor can a match with the same teams but another order happen, because the current team is not part of the helper array and was therefore never before considered.

The result will be:

```
$matches = [
    'A' => [
        [2, 1],
        [3, 1],
        [3, 2],
        [4, 1],
        [4, 2],
        [4, 3]
    ],
    ...
];
```

Comment: Thanks Philipp with such a fast reply. Really Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
    $group1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
    $match  = array();


    foreach( $group1 as $team1 ){
        foreach( $group1 as $team2 ){
            //Test if team1 is not equaled to team2 ( cant be 1vs1 )
            //Test if match has no team1vsteam2
            //Test if match has no team2vsteam1
            //If yes to all, add to the match variable
            if ( $team1 != $team2 && !in_array( $team1 . "vs" . $team2, $match ) && !in_array( $team2 . "vs" . $team1, $match ) ) $match[] =  $team1 . "vs" . $team2;
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $match );
    echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to: (Which has 6 counts)

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1vs2
    [1] => 1vs3
    [2] => 1vs4
    [3] => 2vs3
    [4] => 2vs4
    [5] => 3vs4
)
```

Comment: Thanks Eddie with such a fast reply. Really Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: I haven't tested this code since it's off the top of my head.**

You will want to iterate through each of the groups, and setup a "match" with all of the other "teams" in the group. For example, for group A, you would start with the first value (1), and then set a match with 2, 3 and 4. Something like this should do it:

```
$matches = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
    // Get the current team number.
    $t = $array[$i];

    // Iterate through all the teams in this group.
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        // We don't want to set up a match with two of the same team, 
        // So only do it for teams that are different.
        if ($a != $t) {
            // Add our match to the array.
            array_push($matches, array($t, $a));
        }
    }
}
```

`$matches` is an array storing all of the matches for the teams that you have.

Comment: Thanks Morgan with such a fast reply. Really Appreciated.